# List all the user in weblogic by java

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

Does anyone know how to list all the weblogic users in java?
For instance, there is 5 users in security realm, and I want to get all of them. How do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy. For future reference, if you want to look up something like "how do I do X with weblogic and Java..." use `JMX` in your google search. Here is an example from [weblogic wonders](https://weblogic-wonders.com/list-users-and-groups-in-weblogic-using-jmx/). Note you will need to change your URL and user/password in the code:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.management.MBeanInfo;
import weblogic.jndi.Environment;
import weblogic.management.runtime.ServerRuntimeMBean;
import weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultAuthenticatorMBean;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.UserReaderMBean;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.GroupReaderMBean;
import weblogic.management.MBeanHome;
import weblogic.management.WebLogicMBean;
import weblogic.management.tools.Info;
import weblogic.management.Helper;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.*;

public class ListUsersAndGroups
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  MBeanHome home = null;
  try
  {

    Environment env = new Environment();
    env.setProviderUrl(“t3://localhost:7001?);
    env.setSecurityPrincipal(“weblogic”);
    env.setSecurityCredentials(“weblogic”);
    Context ctx = env.getInitialContext();

    home = (MBeanHome)ctx.lookup(“weblogic.management.adminhome”);

    weblogic.management.security.RealmMBean rmBean = 
   home.getActiveDomain().getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();

    AuthenticationProviderMBean[] authenticationBeans = 
    rmBean.getAuthenticationProviders();
    DefaultAuthenticatorMBean defaultAuthenticationMBean = 
    (DefaultAuthenticatorMBean)authenticationBeans[0];
    UserReaderMBean userReaderMBean = 
    (UserReaderMBean)defaultAuthenticationMBean;

    String userCurName = userReaderMBean.listUsers(“*”, 100);

    while (userReaderMBean.haveCurrent(userCurName) )
    {
      String user = userReaderMBean.getCurrentName(userCurName);
      System.out.println(“\n User: ” + user);
      userReaderMBean.advance(userCurName);
    }

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
}
```

EDIT

---

There isn't really any way around have to know the user/password to look up the users. You can do it via WLST scripting as well if that sounds like a better option. See an example [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6678).

Last but not least, you could set anonymous bind on the embedded ldap for Weblogic to allow anonymous lookups (which is generally not recommended for production). This sample shows how to do it with an external client: [Weblogic w/External Ldap Client](http://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/weblogic-embedded-ldap-with-an-external-ldap-client/)

The key settings are:

```
Your Domain -> Security -> Embedded LDAP
Change the (default generated) password (for example: weblogic)
Enable “Anonymous Bind Allowed”
```

Comment: Yes, we can do it by this way. But there's still one problem: you have to put username and password in your code. I know that we can read those information from boot.properties, but do you have any other way? I dont want to use JMX much.

Comment: Edited with some more info that may be of use

Comment: I am using the same procedure which you have mentioned but i am getting  "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy696" on this line 
" DefaultAuthenticatorMBean defaultAuthenticationMBean = 
    (DefaultAuthenticatorMBean)authenticationBeans[0];  "