# How to read weblogic configured myrealm users and passwords using java

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am trying to read user name and password which are configured in myrealm. Is there any way? Or If I create the user in myrealm where it is going to be store. Can I find the file location or file name.

Getting user names code was available in [List all the user in weblogic by java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650838/list-all-the-user-in-weblogic-by-java)
link. But I am expecting password also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all the user in weblogic by java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650838/list-all-the-user-in-weblogic-by-java)

Comment: @TrentBartlem Thank you. In that URL we are getting user names. how to get password also

Comment: Passwords are deliberately difficult to get. You probably have to read from the WLS filesystem, and connect to the server to use the password decryption classes. See https://blog.netspi.com/decrypting-weblogic-passwords/ for more details.

Comment: @TrentBartlem  According to me Prabha is asking for password event if it is encrypted

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The technique is to find the users inside DefaultAuthenticator via JMX, then sneak onto the filesystem and decrypt the password store and extract them that way. As I said, 'deliberately difficult to get'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach. It still would need your weblogic password, but it should give you access to all the users you need.

```
import javax.naming.*; 
import javax.management.MBeanInfo;
import weblogic.jndi.Environment; 
import weblogic.management.runtime.ServerRuntimeMBean;
import weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultAuthenticatorMBean;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.UserReaderMBean;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.GroupReaderMBean;
import weblogic.management.MBeanHome;
import weblogic.management.WebLogicMBean;
import weblogic.management.tools.Info;
import weblogic.management.Helper;
import weblogic.management.security.authentication.*;

public class ListUsersAndGroups {   public static void main(String[]args)   {

  MBeanHome home = null;   try   {

    Environment env = new Environment();
    env.setProviderUrl(“t3://localhost:7001?);
    env.setSecurityPrincipal(“weblogic”);
    env.setSecurityCredentials(“weblogic”);
    Context ctx = env.getInitialContext();

    home = (MBeanHome)ctx.lookup(“weblogic.management.adminhome”);

    weblogic.management.security.RealmMBean rmBean = home.getActiveDomain().getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();

    AuthenticationProviderMBean[] authenticationBeans = 
    rmBean.getAuthenticationProviders();
    DefaultAuthenticatorMBean defaultAuthenticationMBean = 
    (DefaultAuthenticatorMBean)authenticationBeans[0];
    UserReaderMBean userReaderMBean = 
    (UserReaderMBean)defaultAuthenticationMBean;

    String userCurName = userReaderMBean.listUsers(“*”, 100);

    while (userReaderMBean.haveCurrent(userCurName) )
    {
      String user = userReaderMBean.getCurrentName(userCurName);
      System.out.println(“\n User: ” + user);
      userReaderMBean.advance(userCurName);
    }

  }   catch (Exception e)   {
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }   
  }
}
```

Mentions to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650838/list-all-the-user-in-weblogic-by-java)

Comment: @Prabha already mentioned this thing in his question but he needs password of users not list of all users